# Initialize an array of zeros in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, declaration

I have a declaration of `unsigned char *` for the sake of an encryption key:

```
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";
```

I want to make it so that the key is all `0` (not the ASCII character ‘0’).

---

I'm a bit rusty with C, so I'm declaring it like this:

```
unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Which is giving me warnings, so how can I do this correctly?

Comment: or `unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char []){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` but it would be very strange code.

Comment: I wonder why those questions are still asked ... and answered by users with gold badge who should know better...

Comment: Is the unfriendly attitude necessary? @Jean-François Fabre If it's duplicated then simply refer me to it

Comment: The unfriendly attitude is not particularly directed to you. You could have googled it, but you don't have C gold badge, so that's excusable.

Comment: How about `const unsigned char *key = (const unsigned char *)"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";` or the like?  Do you want to changed `key` later in code?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm searching for the past 10 minutes I didn't find good duplicate for this question cause OP use a pointer and miss his component literal initialization with an array... I think actually this question don't have duplicate. The duplication you find don't answer this question.

Comment: but the link I provided solves the question the same way the answers below solve it. So if it's not a duplicate, the answers below are moot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There are bad answers in my opinion except Vlad answer, that mention compound literal.

Comment: yes, the wierd but valid syntax is something new. OP didn't ask that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write

```
unsigned char iv[16] = { 0 };
```

As for this declaration

```
unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

that tries to use a compound literal then its valid record will look like it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 16 };
    unsigned char *iv = ( unsigned char[N] ){ 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", iv[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate memory for storage:

```
unsigned char iv [16];
memset (iv, 0, sizeof iv);
```

Alternatively:

```
unsigned char *iv = calloc (16);  // allocates and initializes to NUL
```

Comment: I believe `calloc` is also safer since the key won't be allocated at the same relative offset to some other variable.  But note that if `calloc` is used, then `free` must also be used in most cases to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the memset() command.

```
memset(iv, 0, sizeof(*iv))
```

Edit: my mistake, accidentally left out the star for iv

Comment: that doesn't work because `sizeof(iv)` is the size of the pointer

Comment: This is wrong because sizeof(iv) is the size of a pointer. It might be correct using `sizeof(*iv)`, depending on how `iv` is defined.